# Манипуляция объекта

Tags: c#, input, unity3d

Здрасте, а как к примеру сделать что б когда я нажимал влево объект прокручивался по своей оси влево(аналогично и в право), понятно что нужно использовать обработчик событий клавиш, а как заставить обьект крутиться по своей оси? Нужно писать что то типа этого rotation.y += 10 ? И еще, есть обработчик событий для колесика мышки?

```
void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey("left")) {
            print ("left");
            rotation.y += 10;//что тут нужно написать вместо этого бреда?
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
            print ("right");
                       rotation.y -= 10; //что тут нужно написать вместо этого бреда?

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
if (scroll > 0)
    this.transform.Rotate(0, 10 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
else if (scroll < 0)
    this.transform.Rotate(0, -10 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```